# Converitr en tiempo real un Stream a byte o byte array

Tags: c#, wpf, axis

```
        string ParamList;
        WaveOut _waveOut = new WaveOut();
        //WaveFileReader reader;
        try
        {
            ParamList = "http://X.X.X.X/axis-cgi/audio/receive.cgi";
            NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(ParamList);
            request.Credentials = networkCredential;

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            SoundPlayer y = new SoundPlayer(ms);

            IWaveProvider reader = new RawSourceWaveStream(
                streamResponse, new WaveFormat());

            _waveOut.Init(reader);
            _waveOut.Play();

        }
        catch (Exception es)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(es.ToString(), "\nError Message");
        }
```

Este es mi codigo y obtengo el audio sin ningun problema, pero el audio esta codificado con uLaw y como ya sabran por esa razon no es entendible. Necesito poder convertir `streamResponse` en un byte array para poder decodificarlo, pero el problema es que estoy Streameando el audio en tiempo real de la camara IP y por lo tanto no puedo hacer un `streamResponse.CopyTo(memoryStream)` debido a que el programa estara leyendo infinitamente por que nunca la API dejara de enviar audio.
Si existe alguna forma de que yo pueda convertir a bytes `streamResponse` en tiempo real seria mi salvacion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer la lectura en un arreglo de bytes directamente de la siguiente manera:

```
...
Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();

//Declaras el arreglo de bytes que servirá como un buffer
byte[] buffer = new byte[32762];

while (true)
{
    int cantidadDeBytesLeidos = streamResponse.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if( cantidadDeBytesLeidos <= 0)
    {
        //Instrucciones a ejecutar si el stream llega a su fin
    }
    //en este punto 'buffer' contiene la cantidad de bytes que fueron leidos del stream
    //y puedes continuar con las conversiones a partir de los datos leidos en buffer

}
```

En el ejemplo, el tamaño del buffer es de 32K pero es posible que tengas que ajustarlo por un tamaño acorde a tu requerimiento.

Ten en cuenta que `streamResponse.Read(...` devuelve la cantidad de bytes leidos y este valor puede ser menor al tamaño del buffer.

En otro orden de ideas, recuerda invocar el método `Dispose()` de todas las clases que implementan la interface `IDisposable` (como los objetos `Stream`) [ver más](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)